# Can client member be the part of team members at task board? how do we manage client entity in scrum?

Tags: project-team, product-owner, external-project-members

I want to manage client member of particular company, but don't know that do we keep team member and client member both entity separate OR both entity as a member list in common?

Comment: Hi Sonali, welcome to the Project Management site of Stack Exchange. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you are looking for and what challenge are you facing. As it's currently written, it’s hard to provide an answer to your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can the client be a member of the team? Sure! It's quite possible that the Product Owner role is taken up by someone from the client. If this is the case though, this person will have to physically be near the team for a decent part of the week and will need to take their role in the team seriously. If the customer simply wants to have oversight, what I have seen done in the past is to have them attend the daily stand-up in the capacity of observer, allowed to watch but not allowed to speak.

You generally don't want to have multiple people from the client all in the team, unless they are actively fulfilling different roles. If multiple people are concerned, then one should be the Product Owner and he/she should communicate with the other people on the client's side to ensure everyone's needs are being met.